# The concept of graded field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I don't know whether my question is a basic one or not. I was reading the definition of Maximal graded ideal and there was a result saying

> For a graded commutative ring a graded ideal is maximal if and only if its quotient is a graded field.

So now my question is suppose $A$ is a graded $k$ algebra, $k$ is a field, such that

$A =\oplus A_i, i\ge 0$ where $A_0=k$.

From here we can write that $k\simeq R/(\oplus_{i\ge 1} A_i)$.

Also we know that $m=\oplus_{i\ge 1}A_i$ is a graded ideal, so can we conclude that $m$ is a maximal graded ideal of $A$ by the previous result? But to conclude this I should know whether $k$ is a graded field or not.

Comment: "maximal+graded" implies "maximal graded", while the converse can be wrong. In fact, a graded field looks like $K[X,X^{-1}]$.

Comment: Dear @user26857: What exactly is a graded field? I'm asking because I don't know the concept and because your example seems to imply that a graded field is not a supplementary structure on a field, since $K[X,X^{-1}]$ is not a field. PS: Glad to see you again!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg A graded field is a $\mathbb Z$-graded commutative ring whose non-zero homogeneous elements are invertible. The definition can be extended to commutative rings graded by abelian groups. (I'm always around, but maybe you missed my comments.)

Comment: Thanks @user26857: that's an interesting definition. And, yes, I suppose I missed your comments but I'm sure I'll read some of them in the future since we have many common areas of interest.

Comment: Thanks @user26857 for clearing the concept  of a graded field.